# iOS 7 issue with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, layoutsubviews

In the app I support iOS 7+. But I can't download a simulator to test it on iOS 7, because the latest simulator available is iOS 8. Everything works fine on iOS 8 and iOS 9. But my customer has iPhone 4 with iOS 7 and when he runs the app, it crashes immediately after launch with error:

**Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super**

I took this error from crashlitics report. May be somebody knows how to correct that?

Answer (score 0):

Check your all `layoutSubviews` methods where you have write and in that method first call `[super layoutSubviews];` .
because before few month I have same problem for ios 7  and then I call `[super layoutSubviews];` In custom cell where I have used `layoutSubviews` method and its working fine for me.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't have any layoutSubviews methods